# autoit: run application and open file from internal menu in silent mode

Tags: autoit, mode, silent

I have an exe-application which I close and run many times in day. Every time when I'm running this application after as it started I must do some actions: choose "File" menu and choose file in there.

This code is worked only if I use `@SW_MAXIMIZE`, but if I run this code with `@SW_HIDE` - application not started with `congiguraion.cfg` file

```
Example()
Func Example()
    Local $iPID = Run("c:\Program Files (x86)\Server.exe", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
    Local $FileName = "c:\Program Files (x86)\congiguraion.cfg"
    Sleep(2000)
    Send("^o")
    Sleep(2000)
    Send($FileName)
    Sleep(500)
    Send("{ENTER}")
EndFunc   ;
```

I want to make exe-file and put it in scheduler with trigger: begin the task at startup. That's why I need to run in silent mode.

P.S.

Also I changed my program:

```
Example()
Func Example()
    Run("c:\Program Files (x86)\Server.exe")
    Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive("Server")
    Sleep(2000)
    ControlSend($hWnd, "", "", "^o")
    Sleep(2000)
    ControlSend($hWnd, "", "", "c:\Program Files (x86)\congiguraion.cfg{ENTER}")
EndFunc   ;
```

This solution also doesn't work if I tried to run it with @SW_HIDE key or on hidden mode in scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [ControlSend](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm). If u want to use it, I suggest to use 'AutoIt Window Info" which is installed with the usual AutoIt installation. With this tool you just got to run the programm and get the control names/ids and fill it into the function.

If you have questions about how ControlSend excatly works feel free to ask :)

```
Example()
Func Example()
    Run("notepad","")
    Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive("Unbenannt - Editor")
    WinSetState($hWnd,"", @SW_HIDE )
    ControlSend($hWnd, "", "", "Sample Text")
        ControlSend($hWnd, "", "", "^o")
        ControlSend($hWnd, "", "", "MyText.txt{ENTER}")
        WinSetState($hWnd,"", @SW_SHOW )
EndFunc   ;
```

Comment: I added the code in main comment where I tried to use ControlSend. This solution also is not worked for me.

Comment: @Isv Oh okay sorry I didn't really looked thru your code. You cant run WinWaitActive if u have an invisible window. It works with notepad. I've added a short example to my answer.

Comment: This solution also doesn't work for me.. Is there another way ?

Comment: For another solution I need to have the server.exe to know how it is build bcause it works good with notepad.